# Ace Magician AMR05 5800U - black screen

Tags: server

Device is Ace Magician AMR05 5800U.

Installing Ubuntu server versions 22+23 cannot be done, as the screen goes black once I select Install Ubuntu Server - even when HWE kernel option is tested. Didn't manage to get anything out of it, the screen is just black.
I managed to install Fedora server, worked like a charm.
Then I tried Ubuntu LTS 18.04, and it worked like a charm, so the hardware is probably not the issue, neither are the BIOS settings.

Once upgraded to 22.04, the HDMI monitor goes black again. The screen is running, but it is just black. I managed to start SSH before the upgrade to 22.04 version, therefore I know, the system is up and running. I can log in - I installed cockpit, looked into journal, but didn't find anything specifically related to this.

```
event_source: Failed to get device name: No such file or directory
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GPIO._EVT due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20221020/psparse-529)
ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20221020/exfldio-261)
kernel
ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECRM] (00000000300ae28b) [EmbeddedControl] (20221020/evregion-130)
amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014
```

`amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014` This caught my eye, but I didn't manage to figure anything out from this message.

I have searched the web, found some clues that lead me in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, but the list isn't specifically blacklisting the amd-igpu.

I have managed to get into grub during the boot. Tried both kernels 6.2.0 + 5.15. Neither is working. Strange thing though, once I boot up into recovery mode, and then immediately select to proceed to normal boot, the screen comes up just fine. My wild guess is that the amdgpu driver is not initialized properly during normal boot, but I have no idea where to look further.

Next scenario: Normal boot, black screen - consumption is 6.5 -7.5W average in idle, but if I go into Recovery mode -> proceed to normal boot, it pulls more, around 8.5W. I would say, that the igpu isn't even started in normal boot. Generally speaking that is my goal, the lowest consumption, but I still would say that this is an error (maybe not, is this expected?), but I can't find anything in the logs.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: I did. Is there anything specific that I should improve?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Unsure how unfortunately and I am unable to recreate the original issue at this moment. (I didint exactly spend days on it, but I did try to revert all the changes I made, and still it is working.)

1. I read https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-amd-gpu-black-screen-boot.html - I played a lot with the kernel boot parameters, mostly amd gpu related.
2. I edited a lot of things in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf + others in folder, method try-fail, commenting/uncomenting different sections related to amd+igpu/microcode and combinations.
3. but lastly I also did some apt update && apt upgrade along, and some part, or the combination of it, solved the issue.

The device is currently pulling slightly more, 7-8W at idle, instead of 6-7W, so igpu is always on.